# What step up/booster transformer would be needed to wire a PTAC unit into 120/240 wiring?

Tags: wiring, hvac

I want to install a 12,000 btu commercial PTAC unit into my backyard studio apartment which has 120/240v wiring.

The info plate has the following ratings:
[image]

- Volts 265. Volt Range 238 to 292.
- Hz 60 PH 1
- EER 11.5
- COP 3.2
- 14.3 amp/3745 watts Resistance Heat
- 5.4 amp/1045 watts Rev. Cyc Heat
- 5.4 amp/1040 watts Cooling
- Compressor RLA 4.3/LRA 23.5|
- Indoor Fan FLA 0.34/HP 0.04/ LRA n/a|
- Outdoor Fan FLA 0.71/ HP 0.10/ LRA n/a|
- Resistance Heater KW 3.70|
- Min Circuit Ampacity 17.9|
- Max Overcurrent Device 20|
- Permanently Wired|
- SHORT-CIRCUIT: 5KA RMS SYMMETRICAL, 600v MAXIMUM

Apartment has 100 amp main breaker. What wiring/transformer setup do I need to make this work?

Comment: Their voltage figures are a bit odd.  Offhand it seems like they want a 20 amp double breaker for 240v.  That will need 12 gauge or can upgrade to 10 gauge wire.  Unknown if you need a neutral wire.

Comment: Removed OP's references to 227V as the nameplate has no reference to 227V.

Comment: This seems as it is designed to work on a single leg of a common commercial 480Y/277 electrical service.  Are you open to the possibility that it might cost more to buy and install the transformers to make this work than it would cost to simply buy a 240V/60/1P unit?

Comment: @ChrisO But based on the specs, it *should* work on a 240V circuit.

Comment: @manassehkatz-Moving2Codidact True, but as you noted in your answer, his 240V would have to be _extremely_ stable to stay in range.  I'm certain it would plug in and power on, but I'm not certain the unit would last long given normal +/-5% fluctuation.

Comment: In my (admittedly limited) experience, there shouldn't be that much fluctuation on a 240V dedicated circuit that is in turn on a reasonably loaded utility feed. The +/- 5% seems in general to be more to allow for voltage drop on long runs and on variation between utilities - not all moved from 220 to 230 to 240 at the same time and some may still be below 240 on their normal voltage. But yes, it is marginal and OP needs to make sure that the baseline is a solid 240.

Comment: If the manufacturer is still in business I wonder if you could simply ask them if the unit would work on a 240 volt circuit.

Answer (score 5):

Found the [manual here](https://hvacdirect.com/media/hvac/pdf/AMANA-PTAC-Service.pdf). This is a nominal 265V unit, but should run at 240V based on the manual and the nameplate.

Based on the manual:

- The HEH123 is really what you should have. The HEH124 is for nominal 265V, which effectively covers 277V and *barely* 240V.
- The HEH124 is supposed to be hardwired:

> Cord connection to a wall socket is not permitted for 265-volt units. All 265-volt units must be hard wired using the hard wire kit or make use of the plug-in receptacle in the standard subbase.

I'm sure the subbase should be hardwired. So if you have the subbase that should include a receptacle to match the plug you currently have, and you will hardwire the subbase to your circuit.

If you don't have the subbase then either this was originally installed elsewhere incorrectly *or* the original installation was with the subbase and somebody gave/sold you the PTAC itself but not the subbase. In either case, you should remove the plug/cord and install this hardwired - installing it plug/cord/receptacle *without* the subbase is violating the manufacturer's instructions and, by extension, violating the NEC.

Assuming you actually have 120V/240V, there is no transformer or anything else special needed. 238V < 240V < 292V. So a simple 20A double-breaker and two hots + ground is all you need.

There are three potential issues:

- Load calculation.

This *shouldn't* be a problem here, as the 100A should already include allowance for some sort of HVAC. But if the apartment originally had, for example, gas heat, and the load calculation was already close to the limit then there could be an issue. But probably OK.

- 120V/240V

Based on what I can see, this system only needs 240V(ish). Some systems actually require 120V/240V - i.e., they have some parts that run on 120V. If so, then you will need a neutral wire in addition to two hots and a ground. It is important to figure out in advance because you can't simply combine neutral and ground. Combining neutral and ground is an old practice that has been against code (except for grandfathered dryers and ranges) for decades. So make sure in advance. You can always run a /3 (3-wire plus ground - black/red/white/bare) cable and cap the white if it isn't needed this time.

- 240V vs. 208V

Most residential housing in the US is a simple 120V/240V configuration. But some is actually 120V/208V. Mostly this is in large apartment buildings, but not exclusively. Many appliances are designed to handle this - e.g., 200V - 250V. But this particular device is on the high side - lowest permissible is 238V. If you run it at 208V(ish) then it may work OK, it may not work at all, it may work inefficiently, and it may die a horrible death. So double check your nominal hot-hot voltage. That is easiest at a plug-in 240V device (most common is an electric clothes dryer) but if there are none available then you can check it (carefully) in your breaker panel. If you get a voltage of 238V or higher, you're all set. If it is lower then you can't use this device. Note that a transformer is *not* a realistic solution. A transformer can get you from 208V to 250V or higher. But it will cost quite a bit for a transformer to handle this size load, and a far better solution is to get a different HVAC system that will work with your available voltage.

Comment: I find their voltage(265) figure at the top odd for NA.  It does not seem to match common NA voltages(single or three PH) that this unit seems made for.  Just wondering if there are some industrial/commercial power at this voltage?

Comment: @crip659 265 is simply the midpoint of 238 and 292. I am betting that 238 was chosen to (barely) match with a 240V nominal standard residential, with 292V being basically 277V + 5%. So it works with 250V +/- 5% and 277V +/- 5%. What it does *not* work with is 208V (at all) or 240V -more than 1%. So for a 120V/208V it is a definite no-go and for an area with 240V nominal and actual < 238V it also doesn't work.

Comment: 227V was a typo, the plug rating(which i failed to mention) is 277V

Comment: "Plug rating"? Is this an existing receptacle you want to plug into? Or a cord/plug already attached to the PTAC? Or something else? Why plug/receptacle and no thard-wired? If you *must* have plug/receptacle, what existing stuff do you actually have (NEMA type - 6-20, etc.)?

Comment: Cord/plug already attached to the unit, my main concern is the voltage involved. i have the appropriate receptacle. I appreciate the detailed info, I first tried asking this question on a electrical engineering page and didn't get much.

Comment: You *don't* have the appropriate receptacle unless you have the subbase. Because the unit **MUST** be hardwired if you don't use the subbase. I would actually recommend hardwiring even if the manufacturer didn't require it, but the manufacturer does require it, so end of story.

Comment: In your bullet points near the top, you mention `HEH123`, `H124`, and `HEH124`. Is the `H124` a typo, or is there something I'm missing?

Answer (score 1):

Well, you could get a 240V/24V transformer and wire it for boosting to kick 240V up to 264V.   It would only need 10% of circuit ampacity, so 500 VA should suffice.  I would probably mount this inside the unit, if feasible, and then just use a normal NEMA 6-20 cord on it.

Do not attempt to wire it as a "science project" outside of an enclosure. Do not wire 264V to a 240V outlet; if you *must* do that on a plug, use NEMA 7-20 type (which is rated 277V/20A hot-neutral-ground).